# Rails - How to make some posts visable to members only?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for the best way to make some posts available only to premium members of my site. I would like for all users and guests to be able to see the links to all posts, but I will have some marked "members only" and if a member clicks on the link then it takes them to the show page of that post id just fine, but if a non-member or guest clicks on it then it take them to the member sign up page and says something like "This post is for members only".

now i can figure out how to do most of this, the only thing im struggling with is how to make the specific posts members only but leave the rest viewable by all.

Answer (score 1):

define a 'before_action' in your controllers that will limit members only.

```
#xxx_controller.rb
class XxxController < ApplicationController
  before_action :members_only, only: [:show, :edit] #modify the 'only'-part
```

then define the method in your ApplicationController

```
#application_controller.rb
def members_only
  #redirect_to "This post is for members only"-page unless member logged in?
end
```

Comment: yeah! my bad. tnx@muistooshort!

Comment: Fernand- Wouldnt this method block ALL non-members from seeing ANY of the :show pages? like for example i would want post:id (1,2,3,5,7,8) viewable by all people who visit my site, while post:id (4 and 6) viewable by members only. so everyone needs to be allowed to navigate to the show page but only certain post id's returnable to the non-members. Thanks

Comment: so how do you determine that the post is viewable by all people and the other post is not? Do you have a flag-column?